# need some trick with text-decoration

Tags: css

**EDIT #3, and finall:**

Ok, so i actually made it happend. Idiotically, however. In case someone will need the same, i'll post a solution here:
What i've did is, basically defined the global  style as below:

```
a:link,a:visited
{
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}
a:hover,a:active
{
color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}
```

That was the very basic parameters i could insert at the global  style. The next move is makin' the same  inside the  link and customize it for ur need as like as u want, hover, make sure u're doin' the copy of that customization of ur div, and insert the :hover thing into it, as following:

```
.some-div-cutomization
{
text-decoration:none!important;
blabla
}
.some-div-cutomization:hover
{
text-decoration:none!important;
blabla
edit if needed the hover function
}
```

That's about it. Have fun :)

I've got some source links, that i can't touch, even to insert the class element, so i would be able to change the style of the links, but i do need somehow to change they style.
So, let's say tag of this link would be [link][/link], so what i did is, put inside it div element with full customization and it's worked, however there's two moments:

1) I don't really know if it's may work properly on all browsers, 'cause i need it cross-browser version actually.

2) i can't get rid of the text-decoration line. i've tried text-decoration with none, and even mad a copy style of that specific div with :hover and put inside it text-decoration none, and still, it's not working.

Also, if there's some another trick to avoid such a thing, please share.

**EDIT:**

I've tried all below, didn't work as i wanted to. **BUT**, i've made it, but with very, very ugly coding, and i'm not sure it's goin' to work at all browsers:
I've inserted the  link-element with underline none inside the one() i can't touch, so now it's link inside another link, witch very ugly.

```
[link-i-cant-touch]<div class="style_test"><a id="no-textdecoration" href="#">somecooltext</a></div>[/link-i-cant-touch]

.style_test
{
text-decoration:none!important;
font-family: 'qsc';
text-align:left;
padding-top:0px;
color:#000000;
}
#no-textdecoration{
text-decoration:none!important;
color:#000000;
}
#no-textdecoration:hover{
text-decoration:none!important;
color:#1982d1;
}
```

**EDIT Num2** 
That didn't work as well, because the link is changed to the second one, so it's redirect for "#"... :/

Comment: a {text-decoration:none !important;}

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you target the `a` tag for the `text-decoration`, rather than applying it to the `div`

`.my-div-class a { text-decoration: none; }`

Comment: in addition to this, pay attention to @caramba comment about using !important. This should prevent the a tag from overwriting your styles in another class. However, the !important may not work on some old browsers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you did wrong, as you haven't posted any code.

But this is the correct way of removing `text-decoration` on links.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#">Link with text decoration</a>
<a id="no-textdecoration" href="#">Link without text decoration</a>
```

**CSS:**

```
#no-textdecoration {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

**Output:** (In image format)

[image: Output of text-decoration fiddle]

[JSFiddle demo: Removing text-decoration from a link](http://jsfiddle.net/3N7Va/)

Comment: The thing is, i'm trying to customize link, that i can't touch. But u actually gave me an idea, witch i describe above at the post under edit section. But it's kinda ugly

Comment: You can't touch the link? You should give it an id as I did and you can touch it. CSS can change EVERY HTML OBJECT on a webpage.

Comment: dude... r u srsly? i can't touch the link means i can't edit the code. why? because. i'm not askin' that just to drive u crazy, right. thanks anyway